# Circular Inheritance in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I have three classes and I want to use each of them inside another
likeso:

```
class Object
{
public:
    Object();
    ~Object();


protected:

   int x;
   int y;
private:
  Line l;
  Circle c;
}; 

class Line : public Object
{
public:
    Line ()
        {
           x = x+y;
         }
    ~Line ();


private:
}; 

class Circle : public Object
{
public:
    Circle()
        {
           x = x/y;
         }
    ~Circle();


private:
};
```

So the problem here is that I get an error on compilation which says base undefined,
I have tried to use `#define` and `#ifdefine`, but it doesn't work.

Ideally, what I want to do is to have one object in `main` to call and all other variables to be used will be set there and at the same time this object could be different such that it could be a `Line` or `Circle`.

Comment: The keyword is `public`, not `Public`

Comment: So what does it mean?

Comment: I'm not sure that what you're asking makes sense: could you please restate the question?

Comment: Yeah, I think you need to rephrase your question since this doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you want any object to be either a primitive graphical object, like a line or a circle, or a compound object, ie. an object containing several others.

Your are actually almost there: what you should do is:

- remove the `Object` subclasses instances from Object (see other answers for the reason behind this being a design mistake),
- create a fourth class inheriting of `Object`:

  ```
  class Compound : public Object {
    public:
      Compound(){
      }
    private:
     Line line;
     Circle circle;
  };
  ```

Now if you want to manipulate in a generic way a list of objects, it's easy. All you need is to define the ad-hoc virtual methods on `Object`, and override them in the subclasses (for instance a `draw` method).

See [this tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/) on polymorphism for more explanations on the concept.

Comment: Yes you're right, I did now by creating other class containing my objects

Answer (score 4):

you cannot do this. It's impossible for the compiler to do it.

Instead you must have pointers to the objects, not direct instances of them.

Then do so called "forward" declarations of the classes:

```
class Circle;
class Line;
class Object
{
    Line* line;
    Circle* circle;
}
```

Of course, it would be better to use smart pointers rather than raw ones.

Answer (score 3):

Just think about it:

1. Each `Object` contains a `Line`;
2. Each `Line` is an `Object`;
3. Therefore, each `Object` contains an `Object`;
4. And of course that `Object` contains in turn an `Object`;
5. Which contains an `Object`... and so on until you get tired.

This is an attempt to set up an **infinitely recursive data structure**, and you can probably see why it is not allowed.

Instead, use [forward declarations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) and (smart) pointers (`unique_ptr<>` seems to be the best choice here) to break the mutual dependency and allow for a termination to the recursive structure (pointer can be null):

```
#include <memory>

// Forward declarations
class Line;    
class Circle;

class Object
{
public:
    Object();
    ~Object();
protected:
   int x;
   int y;
private:
  std::unique_ptr<Line> l;
  std::unique_ptr<Circle> c;
};

class Line : public Object
{
public:
    Line ()
        {
           x = x+y;
         }
    ~Line ();
};

class Circle : public Object
{
public:
    Circle()
        {
           x = x/y;
         }
    ~Circle();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can NOT do what you've just described. The base class must not contain classes that derive from it. When a class derives, it contains all the components of the baseclass. So in your example, Object contains a Line and a Circle. A Circle contains Object which contains Circle and Line - you can see that we can to on just like the number of 3's in 1/3 ...

You can either have a reference or a pointer to an object of class Line or Circel, e.g.

```
class Line;
class Circle
```

You need the above lines BEFORE the Object class - it tells the compiler "There is a class Line and a class Circle. I'll come to what they actually contain later..."

```
class Object
{
public:
    Object();
    ~Object();


protected:

   int x;
   int y;
private:
  Line* l;
  Circle* c;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for a member variable to be of a given type (like '`Circle c`') the class definition must have already appeared in the translation unit.  So, in this case, what you're asking is impossible.

However, a pointer to an object only requires the compiler to know that a symbol (such as 'Circle') represents a class.  You can do this by a [forward class declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration).  So an option is

```
class Circle;
class Line;

class Object {
public:
    ...
    Circle *c;
    Line *l;
}

class Line: public Object { ... }

class Circle: public Object { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code an `Object` object contains a `Circle` sub-object (data member) which in turn contains an `Object` sub-object (base class sub-object), which…

That yields *infinite size*, which is rather ungood.

However, the solution is very simple: don't derive those classes from `Object`.